# cakephp Auth Deny

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using Cakephp1.3, i want to deny some functions

Here is my code which is written in users controller

```
  function beforeFilter(){
     parent::beforeFilter();
     $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
     $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';     
  }    
 function isAuthorized() {    
     $this->deny('delete');
     return true;    
}
```

But i am still able to access delete function .i want to stop access for delete function.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `parent:beforeFilter();` should be `parent::beforeFilter();`

Comment: i tried this Still not working

Comment: Try `$this->Auth->deny('delete')` in your beforeFilter function !!

Comment: i tried this Still not working

Comment: how is your allow part? can you var_dump $this->Auth->allowedActions to see if you have delete there?, can you access delete before login in?

Comment: yes i am able to access before login and also after login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isAuthorized() {    
    if ($this->action == 'delete') return false;  
}
```

and I would put a `pr();` statement somewhere inside of `isAuthorized()` just to make sure you are at least making it to that function.

Comment: Yes, i know this solution but i want to do with deny not by return false;